# Issues with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, performance, requestanimationframe

I have an issue:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
        hello = true
        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            if (hello) {
                document.querySelector('div').style.left = (e.clientX - 12.5) + 'px'
                document.querySelector('div').style.top = (e.clientY - 12.5) + 'px'
            }
        })
        this.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
            hello = false
            posY = Math.floor(parseInt(this.style.top))
            function Fall() {
                posY++
                document.querySelector('div').style.top = posY + 'px'
                if (posY != parseInt(window.innerHeight) - 25) requestAnimationFrame(Fall)
            }
            Fall()
        })
    })
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  overflow:hidden
}

div {
  position:absolute;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  border:1px #000 solid;
  bottom:0
}
div:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In this code ([also on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09p034vo/6/), when I drop the div, I want the div to fall, and stop at the ground.

The first time, it works. But then, `requestAnimationFrame` is faster, it's like the first one isn't done...? And after that, the div didn't stop at the ground :(

Do I have to use `setInterval` instead of `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: *"In this code, (http://jsfiddle.net/09p034vo/6/ if you need the html/css"* The full content of your question must be **in** your question. If you want to make it easy for people to help you, update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Edit: I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I just edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the div is clicked (mousedown) theres another listener assigned. When you stop clicking, these listeners are all executed in order, so at the second click, there will be two loops running, after the third there will be three loops running and so on. You may just assign the listener once:

```
var hello,posY;

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  hello = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    if (hello) {
        document.querySelector('div').style.left = (e.clientX - 12.5) + 'px';
        document.querySelector('div').style.top = (e.clientY - 12.5) + 'px';
    }
});

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    hello = false;
    posY = Math.floor(parseInt(this.style.top));
    function Fall() {
        posY++;
        document.querySelector('div').style.top = posY + 'px';
        if (posY < parseInt(window.innerHeight) - 25) requestAnimationFrame(Fall);
    }
    Fall();
});
```

And please always end a statement with a semicolon...

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! (And sorry for the semicolons, but I prefer like this :p, they are optional !)

Comment: @D.Tritonic they are optional in 90% of the cases. If it becomes a habit to not use them, it will somewhen crash and you dont know why. If you use semicolons it works always...

Comment: @D.Tritonic: They aren't optional, but there is an *error-correction mechanism* built into JavaScript that will insert them for you at the parsing stage. That's not the same thing.

Comment: *"And please always end an expression wirh a semicolon"* *Statement*, not expression. A semicolon goes at the end of a statement that isn't already terminated by a block.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding your `mouseup` handler **every time** the div receives a `mousedown`. You only want to do that once, so move that out of your `mousedown` handler. So you set up the animation twice on the second call (because both handlers respond), three times on the third (because all three handlers respond), etc. And since multiple handlers are updating `poxY`, it doesn't stop at the ground anymore because the `!=` check fails for all but one of them. (See further notes under the snippet.)

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  hello = true
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (hello) {
      document.querySelector('div').style.left = (e.clientX - 12.5) + 'px'
      document.querySelector('div').style.top = (e.clientY - 12.5) + 'px'
    }
  })
})
// Moved the below
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  hello = false
  posY = Math.floor(parseInt(this.style.top))

  function Fall() {
    posY++
    document.querySelector('div').style.top = posY + 'px'
    if (posY != parseInt(window.innerHeight) - 25) requestAnimationFrame(Fall)
  }
  Fall()
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  bottom: 0
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Some other observations:

- Your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — declare your variables
- Rather than re-querying the DOM all the time, it would probably be best to query the DOM for the `div` *once*, and remember it in a variable

* *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: Thank for the answer ! I won't do that again !